# Search data in a complex dialog in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am currently trying to drill down on a user in a dialog where the user placing the bet history. I have worked out how to iterate through the dialog but I'm having trouble actually selecting the latest betting ticket on dialog. I need an advise on how to grab the latest betting data properly by date? or data-id? Kindly advise. Thanks you

Here is the HTML :

```
<li data-id="20151105031Yvx00tr0001" data-istrace="0" class="evenTr first">
    <span class="wd1">2015-11-05 14:25:19</span>
    <span class="wd5">3D福彩</span>
    <span title="二码不定胆">二码不定胆</span>
    <span class="wd2">2015302</span>
    <span class="wd3">元</span>
    <span class="grid-toggle" alt="号码详情：">
        <div class="wrapbox">
            <em alt="047">047</em>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="wd4">53</span>
    <span>¥318</span>
    <span>¥0</span>
    <span class="wd4">未开奖</span>
    <span alt="开奖号码："></span>
    <span class="wd3">否</span>
</li>
```

[Image Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geyRC.jpg)

Comment: please share site URL where we can see that dialog.

Comment: ok and what you have tried to get that latest data? your selenium webdriver code?

Comment: @HelpingHands Hi , i have no idea what to wrote for the code to compare this. , any idea on this advise? Thanks you

Comment: Yes but please share code whatever you tried.